# MVC 6's MemoryCache should be used at a Controller level or at a Service level?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, software-design

Due to ASP.NET Core providing a MemoryCache that can be injected and being singleton, should it be injected in the Controller or in the Service?

I have a Controller which calls a Service to fetch information from a database or a external service. In the controller I will only transform some of that information (a list of objects into a `List<SelectListItem>`).

Should I cache at Service level and return the cached information to the Controller or should I cache the already transformed information (`List<SelectListItem>` or even the service raw information)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service is responsible for the more expensive operation (getting the data from a database or some such). Compared to that, the transformation you're performing in the controller has a negligible performance impact, so putting this responsibility into the controller won't help from a performance perspective.

Also, it's possible that the same service method could be invoked from more than one place, in which case you'd get more benefit from caching in the service layer.

From a "separation of concerns" standpoint, another strategy you could use, which I've had success with, is to move the caching responsibility into its own class.

```
public interface IThingRepository
{
  IReadOnlyCollection<Thing> GetThings();
}
public class ThingRepository : IThingRepository
{
  //...
}
public class ThingRepositoryCache : IThingRepository
{
  IThingRepository realRepository;
  MemoryCache cache;

  public ThingRepositoryCache(IThingRepository realRepository,
    MemoryCache cache)
  {
    this.realRepository = realRepository;
    this.cache = cache;
  }

  public IReadOnlyCollection<Thing> GetThings()
  {
    return cache["things"] ?? cache["things"] = this.realRepository.GetThings();
  }
}
```

With a DI binding something like this, to inject the real repository into the cache whenever someone asks for the repository:

```
Bind<IThingRepository>().ToMethod(c => new ThingRepositoryCache(
   c.Get<ThingRepository>(),
   cache));
```

Answer (score 0):

That's more a controller concern than a service concern.